# Adding kriging results back to a GWR model in R?

Tags: raster, r, kriging, geographically-weighted-regression, residuals

How can I add the kriging results of a downscaling process back to a GWR model? Basically, I have 2 raster, 1 at 400m (let's call it x1) resolution and 1 at 100m resolution. I upscaled the latter to 400m, I performed GWR, I extracted the residuals and then I performed kriging on these residuals in order to downscale them. Now, I want to add them (the downscaled residuals which are in raster format at 100m) back to GWR model so I can produce the x1 at 100m. I am following the paper "[Downscaling MODIS images with area-to-point regression kriging](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S003442571530033X?token=67906D7583F6AC27CAD61337B9F4F824BE825F995BF50FE5760AF3DD5CD2120C65B31048E4E9EE39AD59A49C3BA842A7&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20220223184354), Wang et al., 2015". According to the authors, "*After both regression and ATPK are completed , their outputs (i.e., Zv1 Zv2) are combined to produce the final downscaled result, as indicated in Eq. 1*" (see image attached), where the second part of the equation is the predictions of the regression and ATPK. Can someone help me on how I can do this in R? Here is the code and the [data](https://easyupload.io/a2jcbe):

```
#GWR part
library(spgwr)
library(sf)
library(raster)

block.data = read.csv(file = "path/block.data.csv")

#create separate df for the x & y coords
x = as.data.frame(block.data$x)
y = as.data.frame(block.data$y)

#convert the data to spatialPointsdf and then to spatialPixelsdf
coordinates(block.data) = c("x", "y")
gridded(block.data) <- TRUE

# specify a model equation
eq1 <- ntl ~ pan

# find optimal ADAPTIVE kernel bandwidth using cross validation
abw <- gwr.sel(eq1, data = block.data, adapt = T, gweight = gwr.Gauss);

# fit a gwr based on adaptive bandwidth
ab_gwr <- gwr(eq1, 
              data = block.data,
              adapt = abw, 
              gweight = gwr.Gauss,
              hatmatrix = T, 
              se.fit = T);
#print the results of the model
ab_gwr

sp <- ab_gwr$SDF
sf <- st_as_sf(sp)

map.resids <- as.data.frame(sf$gwr.e)
map.resids <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data=map.resids, coords=cbind(x,y)) 
gridded(map.resids) <- TRUE
r <- raster(map.resids)
writeRaster(r, filename = "path/rsds.tif", format = "GTiff")
#end of GWR

#Kriging part
library(atakrig)

rsds = raster("path/rsds.tif")
pan = raster("path/pan.tif")

rsds.d <- discretizeRaster(rsds, 100); beep(7)
grid.pred <- discretizeRaster(pan, 100, type = "all"); beep(7)
pan.d = discretizeRaster(pan, 100); beep(7)

## area-to-area Kriging
aod.list <-list(rsds = rsds.d, pan = pan.d)
sv.ck <-deconvPointVgmForCoKriging(aod.list, 
                                   model = "Sph",
                                   rd = 0.7,
                                   maxIter = 20); beep(7)

# prediction
pred.ataok <- ataKriging(rsds.d, 
                         grid.pred, 
                         sv.ck$rsds, 
                         showProgress = TRUE); beep(7)

# convert result to raster
pred.ataok.r <-rasterFromXYZ(pred.ataok[,-1]);
plot(pred.ataok.r)
writeRaster(pred.ataok.r$pred, 'path/pred.ataok.r.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```

[image: equation]

Comment: I'm not clear on which outputs correspond to Zv1 and Zv2 but you can add rasters together simply with `rast3 <- rast1 + rast2`. Is that what you are after?

Comment: I have no idea, to be honest. I thought your question was 'how to combine two rasters by adding them?' rather than 'which two rasters should I combine?' You might have better luck on [crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It might be that. One raster is the downscaled residuals for sure.. the other part I don't know

Comment: If you are using the code of Wang et al,  I would guess it is the two rasters that are written to disk (that is purely speculative, without studying the paper).

Comment: Wang et Al, they used Modis bands 1 & 2 do downscale the rest of the bands (not all but it's fine). If we assume that they used only band 1, which rasters you guess they written on disc?

Comment: In your code above it is the variables `r` and `pred.ataok.r$pred` but I really don't know if that corresponds with their results.

Comment: Not sure about that, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to solve it. If not, I will update this answer. So, after performing `kriging` on residuals, I returned to the `GWR` code and I extracted the *prediction column* as `raster` (let's call this pred_gwr), from the `data.frame` called sf (please see the code above). Then, I upscaled the downscaled residuals (let's call them res_krig) to match the pixel size of the pred_gwr and finally, I added the 2 rasters and I resampled the result to 100m. Here is the code:

```
map.pred <- as.data.frame(sf$pred)
map.pred <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(data=map.pred, coords=cbind(x,y)) 
gridded(map.pred) <- TRUE
r <- raster(map.pred)
writeRaster(r, filename = "path/gwr_pred.tif", format = "GTiff")

res_krig = raster("path/res_krig.tif")
gwr_pred = raster("path/ntl_nov.tif")

res_krig = resample(res_krig, gwr_pred, method = 'bilinear')

ntl_downscaled = res_krig + gwr_pred
ntl_downscaled  <- aggregate(ntl_downscaled, fact = 4)
writeRaster(ntl_downscaled, filename = "path/ntl_downscaled.tif", format = "GTiff")
```